# Two raster classes according to cut-off elevation using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, elevation

I've defined a python function to take input raster and elevation and output path. The function should return raster with two values 0 for elevation equal to and greater than given elevation and 1 for rest of the pixels. This is what I've done so far:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteoutput=True
from arcpy.sa import*

def getRaster(input, elevation, outputpath):
    inraster=input
    cutoffelevation=elevation
    arcpy.checkExtension('Spatial')
    outputraster=Raster(inputraster)>cutoffelevation
    outputraster.save(outputpath)
```

Comment: What happens when you try calling your function?

Comment: Have a read of Con http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/ outputraster = arcpy.sa.Con(input >= elevation,0,1) would replace most of your getRaster function... you'll still need to call outputraster.save(outputpath) assuming input is a raster object (might work for a string but might not). Don't forget to del outputraster just after the save or you'll have an unnecessary object filling up your temp space if the process later crashes.

Answer (score 1):

you would have to use 'Con'in spatial analysis. 
for instance your code would have to look like this

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import * 
arcpy.OverwriteOutput= True
def getRaster(inRaster,outRaster)
inRaster = path to raster
OutRaster = Con(inRaster(i.e. the raster you are using),elevation > 0(i.e. if your condition is True), elevation = 0 (i.e. if your condition is false, a "value" option is here to set your condition)
ConRaster.save(path)
```

'Con' is versatile for Map algebra.